# Animating div waterfall in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to animate a waterfall of divs like in duitang.com . i tried the following scripts:

http://jsfiddle.net/XKdKt/3/
http://jsfiddle.net/NFPKc/

The second link seems like it's closest to what I want because the div appears from bottom to top unlike the first and second link, but the div under doesnt scroll with the new div.

Can anyone lead me to the right direction to make it look similar to duitang's?

Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are creating divs in your examples.  On duitang.com, the divs already exist.  They are hidden because they are in a DIV tag that is given a height and width and has overflow set to hidden.  Then, I assume, the padding (or some other value) is altered with javascript to make the inner DIVs move down, and cause the next DIV to be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$('#gen').click(function() {
    var div = $('<div><h6>Another</h6><p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</p></div>').prependTo('body');

    var height = div.outerHeight();
    div.css({
        "marginTop": -height,
        "opacity": 0
    }).animate({
        "marginTop":0,
        "opacity": 1
    }, "slow");
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/NFPKc/7/

Comment: Thanks. I was going to answer my own question using marginTop just like how you did, but couldn't because I don't have enough rep points.